# WPF, how do I trigger ListBox.ScrollIntoView using MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a WPF app where the content of a ListBox is updated when the user presses a button. My initial problem was refocusing the ListBox to a specific SelectedIndex value which is binded to an ActiveItem property in my ViewModel. I was able to solve this issue with the following code:

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfItems}" SelectedIndex="{Binding ActiveItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" x:Name="ListBoxSelector">
```

Code-behind:

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxSelector.ScrollIntoView(ListBoxSelector.SelectedItem);
    }
```

However, I currently have the above code-behind in the MainWindow.xaml.cs file instead of my ViewModel. My question is how do I move this code to the ViewModel so that I can stick to the MVVM pattern? I can't quite figure out how to properly address the ScrollIntoView property of the ListBox from the ViewModel.

Comment: I think there is no way. Normally VM part of MVVM responds for data binding, not for UI control. The thing you want to do is specific for WPF, so, if you will move your view models to another project (Xamarin for example) - the code you want to reach wouldn't work. Of course, you can pass your list box as an argument of ViewModel's constructor and do scroll into view when the bonded property is changed, but that's not the best idea

Comment: If  you are using MVVM light, you might consider using messages to notify the window that you would like to scrollintoview.

Answer (score 1):

You can force the selected item to scroll into view using a [`Behavior`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/design-tools/expression-studio-4/ff726531(v=expression.40)) class.

```
public class perListBoxHelper : Behavior<ListBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private static void AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listBox = sender as ListBox;

        if (listBox?.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        Action action = () =>
        {
            listBox.UpdateLayout();

            if (listBox.SelectedItem != null)
                listBox.ScrollIntoView(listBox.SelectedItem);
        };

        listBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
    }
}
```

More details on my [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-behaviors-listbox/).

Also, personally I'd bind to `SelectedItem` of the ListBox rather than `SelectedIndex`, and handle any processing on item selection in that property setter, rather than using an event handler.

Comment: Behaviors really are the best solution to these types of problems in MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

The MVVM pattern doesn't preclude the use of code behind. In fact, it can't because there are cases where code behind is *the right thing to do*. A view model is a model, it is not a view replacement. Another way to think about it is that the view model contains the *what* and the view contains the *how*. At least, this is my interpretation of the MVVM pattern.

In your case, the *what* are the list of items and the current item. The *how* is the `ListBox` itself and its default behavior. It seems to me that scrolling the selected item into view is an additional behavior, and therefore should be kept in the view. You're not violating the MVVM pattern because you're keeping the *what* in the view model and the *how* in the view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've just been under the impression from that MVVM tutorials that I've looked at that it's bad practice to have code in the MainWindow.xaml.cs file.

Comment: @alduin I would say that it's bad practice to have certain kind of code in the code behind, but not all. You definitely don't want to have business logic in your code behind. In my opinion, you shouldn't even have business logic in your view models.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Still quite new to MVVM pattern so trying to work my way through.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my solution is MVVM pattern.But to such problem,it can resolve the problem.

Here is what I will do: If Button is pressed ,it will trigger a command to call method in ViewModel.When ViewModel finish it's job, viewModel throw an custom event(where include item index where listbox should scroll into). And before this happen, when View is Loaded,View's Code-behind should listen to it's ViewModel through View's DataContext, and do scrollIntoView.

As I said,I'm not sure if it's MVVM way,But I thought it's acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't the universal solution for every request regarding this and as others have mentioned MVVM doesn't mean that there is no code behind but no unnecessary code behind.

However in your particular request there is the solution if you want no code behind - make a class that inherits from `ListView` and handles request as you would like it to be handled and then use it in your XAML.